# Return a list where any string in one list starts with any string in another

Tags: python, list-comprehension

In Python I'm attempting to use a list comprehension to create a list where any string in one list starts with any string in another.

For example, say I have a list of three names `Alan`, `Bob` and `Carl`. I wish to return a list of  names that start with any string from another list, this time containing `Bo`, `Da` and `Fr`. There for I'd expect only `['Bob']` to be returned.

However, using the following example I'm seeing all of the names returned.

```py
>>> starts_with=('Bo', 'Da', 'Fr')
>>> names = ['Alan', 'Bob', 'Carl']
>>> [n for n in names if [n.startswith(s) for s in starts_with]]
['Alan', 'Bob', 'Carl']
```

My issue seems to be that the inner list comprehension is returning a list of boolean values, so the list that is being checked by the `if` in the main list comprehension is never empty.

```py
>>> starts_with=('Bo', 'Da', 'Fr')
>>> ['Alan'.startswith(s) for s in starts_with]
[False, False, False]
>>> ['Bob'.startswith(s) for s in starts_with]
[True, False, False]
>>> ['Carl'.startswith(s) for s in starts_with]
[False, False, False]
```

How can I amend my code so that only `['Bob']` is returned?

Comment: please consider extending your sample data to contain a second prefix of Bob, like `('Bo', 'Da', 'Fr', 'B')`. is it ever possible that your list of prefixes may contain one string that is the prefix of another (like 'B' is a prefix of 'Bo')?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, in my case that will never be a possibility, but thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `any()`, which is a builtin function that returns `True` if `any` element of an input iterable is true:

```
>>> starts_with=('Bo', 'Da', 'Fr')
>>> names = ['Alan', 'Bob', 'Carl']
>>> [n for n in names if any(n.startswith(s) for s in starts_with)]
['Bob']
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, I forgot about the existence of `any()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using `any()` with a simple double `for` loop comprehension:

```
starts_with=['Bo', 'Da', 'Fr']
names = ['Alan', 'Bob', 'Carl']


out = [i for i in names for j in starts_with if i.startswith(j)]
print(out)
```

> > ['Bob']

Comment: OP strictly asked for list comprehension solution

Comment: @himanshu-poddar You're right, I have edited the answer and added a 2 `for` loop comprehension

Answer (score 1):

Simple and compact solution

```
[n for n in names for sw in starts_with if n.startswith(sw)]
```

As David asked why not use `any` instead :

Unraveling Samwise [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72831655/10216112)

```
[n for n in names if any(n.startswith(s) for s in starts_with)]
```

would be

```
for n in names:
    for s in starts_with:
        [add s to temp list say temp]
    for t in temp:
        if(t): # if t is true
            [add n to result list]
```

**EDIT :** As discussed in comments, Samwise answer is more efficient `With the any, the inner loop gets short-circuited on a true result because it's a generator expression (so it just stops pulling from the iterator once it has its answer)`

So Samwise answer actually becomes

```
for n in names:
    for s in starts_with:
        if n.startswith(s):
            break and add the element to the result list
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. Do you know if this solution has any advantages over using `any()` [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72831655/567059)?

Comment: @DavidGard I think any has one disadvantage, it will loop through the generated list again to check if `True` value is present, just a double loop would be more efficeint

Comment: OK thanks, I think I'm going to use this solution.

Comment: Both solutions involve a loop inside a loop; `any` is actually more efficient because it'll short-circuit the inner loop as soon as a true condition is met.  The "unraveled" version of `any` in this answer is not at all how the function works.

Comment: @Samwise we are talking about the worst case here, what if the elemnt we are actually interested in is presennt at the end here, it will have to go until end right?

Comment: Yes, but your solution will always go to the end no matter what.  It also assumes only one intersection, which is valid for this particular case but not in the general case.

Comment: But atleast it does not involve a second loop, does any stops the execution of `for s in starts_with` in your case as well?

Comment: `for n in names for sw in starts_with` is two loops, even though they produce one list; it produces the product of the two lists (that is, nine elements), each element of which has to be evaluated against the final `if`.  With the `any`, the inner loop gets short-circuited on a true result because it's a generator expression (so it just stops pulling from the iterator once it has its answer).

Comment: Well in that case, I was wrong @David I am sorry, Samwise answer is more efficient

Comment: @Samwise check my edits please, and let me know if this is what is actually happening

Comment: Yup, that's more like it.  It's mildly awkward to implement without a function which is exactly why `any` exists to make it less awkward.  :)